# When does ERROR occurs in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I'm a student and right now going through exceptions and errors in Java.

I have a confusion about when error occurs. Please share with me some examples.

Answer (score 10):

Errors are `Throwable`s that you're not supposed to / expected to catch, such as `OutOfMemoryError` or `StackOverflowError`.

From [the Java documentation on `Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An Error is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application **should not try to catch**. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

Here are some of the more common errors:

- `OutOfMemoryError`
- `StackOverflowError`
- `AssertionError`
- `NoClassDefFoundError`

Here are the remaining errors in the standard API:

- `AnnotationFormatError`
- `AWTError`
- `CoderMalfunctionError`
- `IOError`
- `FactoryConfigurationError`
- `FactoryConfigurationError`
- `LinkageError`
- `ServiceConfigurationError`
- `ThreadDeath`
- `TransformerFactoryConfigurationError`
- `VirtualMachineError`
- `InternalError`
- `UnknownError`
- `ClassCircularityError`
- `ClassFormatError`
- `ExceptionInInitializerError`
- `IncompatibleClassChangeError`
- `UnsatisfiedLinkError`
- `VerifyError`

Answer (score 3):

Errors are generally used to signal serious technical problems that an application can't do anything to correct. Look at the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) of the error classes and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you run out of memory -- kaboom! [OutOfMemoryError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)! (There really is not much you can expect to do at this point but let the process die and try to restart it - e.g. the very act of trying to respond to this requires memory so it's a catch-22 :-/)

Answer (score 0):

Errors are something you have little or no control over, typically signifies serious problem.